# Control last page filling

Tags: grid-typesetting

It is possible to create a macro, which is determine a percentage of last page filling. Say, if the last page filled less than 3/4, then macro write a warning to the page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\ifdim\pagetotal<.75\pagegoal\@latex@warning{the last page filled less than 3/4}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-17]
\end{document}
```